# Version mismatch in xcactivitylog after upgrading to XCode 4.2

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode4.2

I upgraded to XCode 4.2 and am getting the warning below while running command line builds

> 2011-10-22 20:16:39.327 xcodebuild[71845:1903] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open Build log store: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "deserialization of log failed because of a version number mismatch" UserInfo=0x4011105e0

The build continues to succeed.
Also, there's no such warning while running from XCode.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this problem too and was able to resolve it by cleaning my project, removing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP` and then rebuilding.